# Sitecore Solr Indexing-> Indexing Manager is failing to update the Solr indexes

Tags: solr, sitecore

I am setting up Solr on my local machine for Sitecore 8.1.

1. I have installed bitnami Solr 4.10, Solr is running correctly.
2. Generated Schema.xml file from Sitecore Control Panel.
3. Created Few indexes by making replica of the existing index.
4. All the indexes are showing up correctly when i open indexing manager

**Problem**

When I rebuild the indexes using Indexing manager-> It says Reindexing complete BUT not processing any items, Snapshots attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT7r4.png)

When I check the log files -> Its not giving any use full info.

Please help, I am attaching the log file snap and the indexing manager snap.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n7hq.jpg)

Comment: Have you enable the solr default configuration and disable the lucene one?

Comment: Yes. All Lucene related Configurations have been disabled and Solr related are Enabled. but status is still the same :-(

Comment: Have you created the solr cores for the corr and master indexes? Moreover you may need to check logs on the Solr Server

Comment: Hi Hishaam,Yes I have created the Core, Master indexes on Solr. No Info on Solr Logs :( i am on Solr 4.10. Any other settings which needs to be checked?

Comment: Sitecore Log snapshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT7r4.png

Comment: Sitecore Indexing Manager snapshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n7hq.jpg

Comment: Do you have the Solr Default Index Configuration config file in the Include Folder

Comment: Yes, I do have that and its enabled also- Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config